# Proving $1 + \tan^2 40^\circ = \sec^2 40^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Recently I have come across this trigonometry question which I cannot seem to solve.

> $$1 + \tan^2 40^\circ = \sec^2 40^\circ$$

Using my current knowledge of trigonometry I am able to get to this:

$$\cos^2 40^\circ + \sin^2 40^\circ + \frac{\sin^2 40^\circ}{\cos^2 40^\circ} = \sec^2 40^\circ$$

But I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: This follows from a well known trigonometric identity, namely that $ 1 + \tan^{2} \theta = \sec^{2} \theta$

Comment: James, can you see that there's nothing to verity here? You are stating an identity subject to a specific value, nothing to prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally
$$1+\tan^2 x=1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}=:\sec^2{x}.$$
Yours is just the particular case $x=40$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $$\frac{cos^2x + sin^2x}{cos^2x} = \frac{1}{cos^2x}$$ Edit 1: I shall answer my own question: $$\frac{1}{cos^2x} = \frac{cos^240}{cos^440} = sec^2x$$

Comment: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. Nothing else

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{opposite}^2+\text{adjacent}^2= \text{hypotenuse}^2$$

$$ \left({\text{opposite} \over \text{adjacent}}\right)^2+1 = \left({\text{hypotenuse} \over \text{adjacent}}\right)^2$$

$$ \tan^2\theta+1 = \sec^2 \theta$$